# Link two tables based on conditions in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I am using matlab to prepare my dataset in order to run it in certain data mining models and I am facing an issue with linking the data between two of my tables.

So, I have two tables, A and B, which contain sequential recordings of certain values in a certain timestamps and I want to create a third table, C, in which I will add columns of both A and B in the same rows according to some conditions.

Tables A and B don't have the same amount of rows (A has more measurements) but they both have two columns:

- 1st column: time of the recording (hh:mm:ss) and
- 2nd column: recorded value in that time

Columns of A and B are going to be added in table C when all the following conditions stand:

1. The time difference between A and B is more than 3 sec but less than 5 sec
2. The recorded value of A is the 40% - 50% of the recorded value of B.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please add a [mcve] with the code you've already tried, list any errors you get and explain why this code is not working and what you want it do do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first condition you need something like `[row,col,val]=find((A(:,1)-B(:,1))>2sec && (A(:,1)-B(:,1))<5sec)` where you do need to use `datenum` or equivalent to transform your timestamps. For the second condition this works the same, use `[row,col,val]=find(A(:,2)>0.4*B(:,2) && A(:,2)<0.5*B(:,2)`

`datenum` allows you to transform your arrays, so do that first:

```
A(:,1) = datenum(A(:,1));
B(:,1) = datenum(B(:,1));
```

you might need to check the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) on `datenum`, regarding the format your string is in.

```
time1 = [datenum([0 0 0 0 0 3]) datenum([0 0 0 0 0 3])];
```

creates the datenums for 3 and 5 seconds. All combined:

```
A(:,1) = datenum(A(:,1));
B(:,1) = datenum(B(:,1));
time1 = [datenum([0 0 0 0 0 3]) datenum([0 0 0 0 0 3])];
[row1,col1,val1]=find((A(:,1)-B(:,1))>time1(1)&& (A(:,1)-B(:,1))<time1(2));
[row2,col2,val2]=find(A(:,2)>0.4*B(:,2) && A(:,2)<0.5*B(:,2);
```

The variables of `row` and `col` you might not need when you want only the values though. `val1` contains the values of condition 1, `val2` of condition 2. If you want both conditions to be valid at the same time, use both in the `find` command:

```
[row3,col3,val3]=find((A(:,1)-B(:,1))>time1(1)&& ...
(A(:,1)-B(:,1))<time1(2) && A(:,2)>0.4*B(:,2)...
 && A(:,2)<0.5*B(:,2);
```

The actual adding of your two arrays based on the conditions:

```
C = A(row3,2)+B(row3,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response and help! However for the time I followed a different approach by converting `hh:mm:ss` to seconds that will make the comparison easier later on:

```
dv1 = datevec(A, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF ');
secs = [3600,60,1];
dv1(:,6) = floor(dv1(:,6));
timestamp = dv1(:,4:6)*secs.';
```

Now I am working on combining both time and weight conditions in a piece of code that will run. Should I use an `if` condition inside a `for` loop or is a `for` loop not necessary?